# Return day of month as 4th instead of 4

Tags: c#, .net

Is there an API in the .NET framework that returns an alphanumeric suffix along with the day of the month, given a `DateTime` instance, like so?

```
4th March 2019
instead of 
4 March 2019
```

or

```
21st October 2018
instead of
21 October 2018
```

I am not asking how to write it. If there isn't an API, I'll write a simple function that does the job. Just asking so it doesn't turn out I am re-inventing the wheel.

I am using .NET Framework 4.6.2.

Comment: Have a look at Humanizer package https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer

Comment: Sorry, but the member with over 12k reputation should know how to use SO, Google, etc...